# Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'vcsrepo'

Tags: git, automation, puppet, devops

I am deploying my code using puppet. I am trying to clone code from git repo

```
vcsrepo { "/home/$server_admin/public_html":
        ensure   => latest,
        owner    => "$server_admin",
        group    => "$server_admin",
        provider => git,
        require  => [ Package["git"] ],
        source   => "$server_gitrepo",
        revision => "$server_gitbranch",
    }
```

when executing script on client machine.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'vcsrepo' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/alpha/manifests/source.pp, line: 32, column: 4) on node
```

Note: git already installed on client machine

Answer (score 2):

The error is being reported on the Puppet server.  It has nothing to do with whether Git is installed on the client.  In fact, it hasn't much to do with Git at all.

Puppet is complaining -- fairly clearly, in fact -- that it doesn't recognize the `vcsrepo` resource type you are trying to use.  That indeed is not a built-in resource type, so if you have not written a custom type by that name or obtained one from a module then Puppet doesn't know what you're talking about.

Quite possibly you're looking for the [puppetlabs/vcsrepo](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) module, which indeed provides a type by that name, but it's impossible for us to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `vcsrepo`.

In order for me to test your setup, I used [puppet-learning-vm](https://github.com/azbarcea/puppet-learning-vm) to setup a sandbox:

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo su -
# puppet --version
6.0.5
```

All modules installed, can be checked with:

```
# puppet module list --environment production
```

In order to check for your module, one can run (if it is not found by Puppet in the environment you're running - I guess is `production` - you will get the error you mentioned):

```
# puppet module list --environment production  2> /dev/null | grep vcsrepo
```

To add a module from the [forge](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo), you should run (in my case, default repository to look for modules is configured to `localhost`, so I had to provide full path to the `forge.puppet.com`):

```
# # puppet module install --module_repository=https://forge.puppet.com puppetlabs-vcsrepo
Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forge.puppet.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└── puppetlabs-vcsrepo (v3.0.0)
```

Now, search for modules installed locally you should be able to see your module installed:

```
# puppet module list --environment production  2> /dev/null | grep vcsrepo
└── puppetlabs-vcsrepo (v3.0.0)
```

From now on, you can use the class `vcsrepo` (provided by the module [`puppetlabs-vcsrepo`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo)). To understand a little bit how it works, the module is actually cloned/retrieved from `forge` and installed in one of the `modulepath`:

```
# puppet config print modulepath
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

```
# find /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules -type d -name vcsrepo | grep -v lib | grep -v spec
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/vcsrepo
```

Another option to have it installed is using `r10k` or `puppet code deploy` (that uses `r10k` internally, both solution using the `Puppetfile`, that usually resides in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/`